# Prevent anyone to access my EC2 instance content on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

I am using a shared AWS account (Everyone in the account has root access) to deploy servers on an EC2 instance that I created. Is there a way to prevent anyone else that have access to the same AWS account to access the content that I put on the EC2 instance?

As far as I know, creating a separate key pair won't work because someone else can snapshot the instance and launch it with another key pair that they own.

Comment: When it comes to access security, you either have 100% security or none. If other users have root access, you cannot prevent them from doing what they want to your instance. They can delete, modify, clone, and access. There are methods to make this more difficult, but anyone with solid experience will bypass these methods.

Comment: It's ok if they delete/modify/clone. The instance contains some sensitive info. I only need to prevent others from seeing it.

Comment: Separation of Access. Create a new account.

Comment: I know that is a solution. But no, we can't separate account. That's the requirement.

Comment: Then you cannot achieve your objective. You cannot prevent them from accessing your data (seeing your data).

Comment: If you are sure about that, you can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using a shared AWS account (Everyone in the account has root
>   access) to deploy servers on an EC2 instance that I created. Is there
>   a way to prevent anyone else that have access to the same AWS account
>   to access the content that I put on the EC2 instance?

No, you cannot achieve your objective.

When it comes to access security, you either have 100% security or none. If other users have root access, you cannot prevent them from doing what they want to your instance. They can delete, modify, clone, and access. There are methods to make this more difficult, but anyone with solid experience will bypass these methods.

My recommendation is to create a separate account. This is not always possible, as in your case, but is a standard best practice (separation of access/responsibility). This would isolate your instance from others.

There are third-party tools that support the encryption of data. You will not be able to store the keys/passphrase on the instance. You will need to enter the keys/passphrase each time you encrypt/decrypt your data.

> As far as I know, creating a separate key pair won't work because
>   someone else can snapshot the instance and launch it with another key
>   pair that they own.

With root access, there are many ways to access the data stored on your instance's disk. Clone the disk and just mount it on another instance is one example.

Answer (score 1):

**By default, IAM Users do not have access to any AWS services.** They can't launch any Amazon EC2 instances, access Amazon S3 data or snapshot an instance.

However, for them to do their work, it is necessary to assign permissions to IAM Users. It is **generally recommended *not* to grant Admin access to everyone**. Rather, people should be assigned sufficient permissions to do their assigned job.

Some companies separate Dev/Test/Prod resources, giving lots of people permission in Dev environments, but **locking-down access to Production**. This is done to ensure continuity, recoverability and privacy.

Your requirement is to prevent **people from accessing information on a specific Amazon EC2 instance**. This can be done by using a keypair that only you know. Thus, nobody can login to the instance.

However, as you point out, **there can be ways around this** such as copying the disk (EBS Snapshot) and mounting it on another computer, thereby gaining access to the data. This is **analogous to security in a traditional data center** — if somebody has physical access to a computer, they can extract the disk, attach it to another computer and access the data. This is why traditional data centers have **significant physical security** to prevent unauthorized access. The AWS equivalent to this physical security are IAM permissions that grant specific users permission to perform certain actions (such as creating a disk snapshot).

If there are people who have Admin/root access on the AWS account, then they can do whatever they wish. This is by design. If **you do not wish people to have such access**, then do not assign them these permissions.

Sometimes companies face a trade-off: They want Admins to be able to do anything necessary to provide IT services, but they also want to protect sensitive data. An example of this is an HR system that contains sensitive information that they don't want accessible to general staff. A typical way this is handled is to put the HR system **in a separate AWS Account** that does not provide general access to IT staff, and probably has additional safeguards such as **MFA and additional audit logging**.

**Bottom line:** If people have physical access or Admin-like permissions, they can do whatever they like. You should either restrict the granting of permissions, or use a separate AWS Account.